# Trying to run some jQuery inside a Wordpress PHP loop to target a dynamic title and rotate title around mouse using Circle library in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In WordPress, I am trying to use jQuery to grab a dynamic title from a WPQuery based on its post_id. I am then using jQuery to make the mouse display and follow the post's title based on a hover function targeting a dynamic div based on the post_id. Finally, I'm using a circle function to make the title rotate around the mouse.

I've got it working but it is quite buggy. When I didn't have the script inside of the loop it only ever identified the last posts title on the page. I'll add my code below. It feels as though the jQuery functions are looping and it is not acting as how it should. The title changes when the mouse enters into a new div, however, the circle seems to increase in size and feels buggy. It worked fine for a targeted div when not in the loop. It is just when inside the loop it might be looping. My understanding of jQuery with WP is not where it should be, so possibly somebody will notice something straight away. Thanks.

As it works now. The circular title seems to jump up and down in radius and the .circle css does not make it spin around. The css is least of my worry, however. Thanks again.

```
 <head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js">. 
  </script>
 </head>
```

```
<style>
.circle {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
}
</style>
```

```
  <div class="main">

   <?php
     $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
         'post_type' => 'works',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'order' => 'ASC'
       )
     );
   ?>

     <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
         <?php  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
           <?php $postId = get_the_ID(); ?>              
           <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 home-container" id="home-container-<?php echo $postId ?>">
                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                   <div class="home-title">
                    <h6 id="<?php echo $postId ?>" class="circle">
                     <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                     <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    </h6>
                   </div>

                </div>
              </div>

             <script>
               // make circle on element based on entering it's unique div id
               $("div#home-container-<?php echo json_encode($postId); ?>").mouseenter(function(){
                 new CircleType(document.getElementById(<?php echo json_encode($postId); ?>));
               });
             </script>
             <script>                  
               // follow mouse code based on class
               $("div#home-container-<?php echo json_encode($postId); ?>").mousemove(function(e){
                   $(".circle").offset({left:e.pageX - 70, top:e.pageY - 70});
               });
             </script>

          <?php endif; ?>
           <!-- hidden until required for mouse hover
              <h3><php the_title(); ?></h3> -->
       <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php else : ?>
       <?php echo wpautop('Sorry, No projects found. Check back soon'); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".circle")` selects _all_ elements with that class, across the whole document. You’ll probably need to limit that to the scope of some ancestor element.

Comment: Btw., nesting `p` into `h6` is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: @CBroe Amazing! Limiting the scope of the element solved the problem. Well spotted. Thank you. If you want to make this an answer I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".circle")` selects *all* elements with that class, across the whole document.

You’ll need to limit that to the scope of the ancestor element.

(Can be done either using `.find()` *from* the ancestor element, or by passing a `context` into `$(…)` as second parameter after the selector.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some changes

From

```
// make circle on element based on entering it's unique div id
$("div#home-container-<?php echo json_encode($postId); ?>").mouseenter(function(){
 new CircleType(document.getElementById(<?php echo json_encode($postId); ?>));
});

// follow mouse code based on class
$("div#home-container-<?php echo json_encode($postId); ?>").mousemove(function(e){
   $(".circle").offset({left:e.pageX - 70, top:e.pageY - 70});
});
```

To

```
// make circle on element based on entering it's unique div id
var postId = "<?php echo $postId; ?>";

$("div#home-container-"+postId).mouseenter(function(){
 new CircleType(document.getElementById(postId));
});

// follow mouse code based on class
$("div#home-container-"+postId).mousemove(function(e){
   $(".circle").offset({left:e.pageX - 70, top:e.pageY - 70});
});
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks a million for the pointer in naming the variable in the script instead of calling it each time. CBroe was on the money with resolving my quesrtion.